# Contact names not displaying with text messages

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia

New Lumia 650: When I receive text messages from people in my Contacts, only the phone number displays (i.e. not the Contact name).

Comment: What contacts? Are they Outlook contacts or Gmail contacts?

Comment: Outlook contacts

Comment: Is the land code specified?